# How to set 0 in first value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make output X3 like this

[image]

where X3 == X2, but the problem is I want to make the first row become 0

What I can do is using =X2 only but I don't know how to convert first rows to 0 for the **same id** because It has so many id and X2

I tried using =(A2=A1)*B2 it work well on sorted id, but the real problem is the id is not sorted, when I use sorted it only give all 0 values

Comment: Try `=(A2=A1)*B2`

Comment: @JvdV omggg I don't know how can this is working? :( but, it doesn't work if the id is not sorted. do you have any solution if the id is not sorted?

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,0,B2)`

Comment: there's a problem with the formula :( @JvdV

Comment: Maybe you need semicolon instead of a comma? "There is a problem" is a bit vague

Comment: @JvdV you're right! Brilliant! thank you so muchhh!!

Comment: @JvdV would you like to help me again with another case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861890/how-can-we-calculate-value-from-previous-row-in-excel Thank you so much because it really helps me a lot ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in the comment, the formula that posted by @JvdV works so well in my case

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,0,B2)
```