# How can we calculate value from previous row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to make X3 output like this

[image]

Where :

First Row of X3 is

**X3 = fixed_cost - X1**

but the second row is calculated by

**X3 from row 1 - X1 from row 2**

and also the problem is the id is not sorted (only sorted by year for each id) and the data is over 100K. Is there any solution for this case? thank you!

I have tried using this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2;A2)=1;C2-D2;F2-D3)
```

But the result is like this

[image]

Any solution? thank you

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,C2-D2,XLOOKUP(A2,A$1:A1,F$1:F1,,,-1)-D2)` for example, or `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,C2-D2,LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1=A2),F$1:F1)-D2)` for older versions of Excel.

Comment: hey @JvdV, I'm just speechless. you're so amazing! Thank you so much! It really helps me a lot!

Comment: You could also place `D2` outside the equation: `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,C2,LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1=A2),F$1:F1))-D2`

Comment: @JvdV you're amazing maan!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let say your table is like so.  In cell F2, enter formula =C2-D2).  this will give you F2.
F3 formula will be =(F2-D3). Then copy paste F3 to F4 and so on.  Hope this help.  There are a lot of formula example online.

Comment: it's okay if I only have a little data. But my data is over 100K I think it will be more efficient if we use one formula to handle the condition. but I don't know how, that's why I asking here ;( But thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If ***C*** column is a constant you can use:

```
=C2-SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,D$2:D2)
```

[image]

Comment: woaah your formula works well too! thank you so muchh! But actually C column is not a consant :(